# Error: #1034, wrong file key for table 'db' try to fix it - phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Error: #1034, wrong file key for table 'db' try to fix it

[image]

I'm trying to create new users in PHPMyAdmin, but I'm getting this error, only pressing Users Accounts... (I have only one user-created, the root) This is my first time trying to create a new one.

```sql
(SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`user` ) 
UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`db` ) 
UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`tables_priv` ) 
UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`columns_priv` ) 
UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`procs_priv` ) 
ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host` ASC
```

Someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Users are store on `mysql.user` table, you don't need `union,` and `remove` distinct from the query because you might have same users with different hosts, in other words they are different. Show the query that you are trying to create the new user

Comment: The solution I have found, has been to unistall xampp, and instal it again and the problem has disappeared.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.